# Creating an OAuth2.0 service provider using RESTify Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, restify

I have a restful API that I built using node.js and node-restify. I am up to the part where I have to secure it. Apparently, it is easy to find out how to use OAuth 2.0 as a client but hard to find out how to set up a provider. I guess my google skills aren't as good as they used to be.

Can someone point me in the direction of where to start? Is there a basic OAuth 2.0 server provider library for node?

I don't have a problem with creating my own library if need be but I looked at the spec, and being that it is a spec, it seems overly complicated. I would think that there would be some sort of tutorial, webcast, or "hello World" style project that broke it down for the dummy in me.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 13):

After some heavy googling, I came up with a lead. I spoke with a kindhearted genius who began work on such a project. He decided to finish up his code and to release it to the world.

The package is called restify-OAuth2.

Here is a link to the [package](https://npmjs.org/package/restify-oauth2). Here is the link to the [github page](https://github.com/domenic/restify-oauth2).

Thanks for all your help Domenic.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you doing the research. Anything in particular I need to be careful about or need to do special to implement restify-OAuth2?